# Let z be a complex number such that $z^2 +z + 1/z^2 + 1/z + 1=0 $

Tags: complex-numbers

If n is a natural number then find the value of  $ z^{2012n} + z^{1006n} + 1/z^{2012n} +1/z^{1006n} $ is equal to.

I tried rewriting it as $ t^2+t-1=0 $ where $ t=z+1/z $ and then find roots but I don't know how to use it to get required value.

Comment: $z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1=0$ so what is $z$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

As $z\ne0,$  multiply throughout by $z^2$

$$z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1=0\implies z^5-1=(z-1)(z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1)=0\implies z=e^{2\pi m i/5}$$ where $m\equiv1,2,3,4\pmod5$

Comment: Can I take n=1 and then divide all powers by 5 and write remainder, which will give $ z^2 +z + 1/z^2 + 1/z $ ?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.**  Rewrite the condition on $z$ as

$$
\frac{z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1}{z^2} = \frac{1-z^5}{z^2(1-z)} = 0
$$

What does that tell you about $z$?  Now consider the possible values of $2012n, 1006n, -2012n, -1006n$ modulo $5$.